# Getting coordinates of a embedded graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have to show how spring embedding works by displaying step-by-step images of a GridGraph[10x10] being embedded from a initial circular form to the final form, which should look somewhat like this: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/ordal/papers/sander/img27.gif

The problem is, I have to do it all with a single-line command in mathematica, which I can't figure out how to do.

The solution that I am currently trying to apply, is:
1) Let X be a circular embedded grid graph.
2) Let Y be a spring embedded grid gaph.
Using the function Grid, I will plot Z(t) = (1-t)*X + t*Y, for t going from 0 to 1 in the steps I need.

This way, I will have n images of a graph going from its circular form (X) to its final desired form (Y).

I know that the function GraphEmbedding[Gaph G, "emb"] gives me all the coordinates I need to solve this problem, but when trying to use:

```
    GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[10, 10], "SpringEmbedding"]
```

I get the following error:

```
    GraphEmbedding::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in RowBox[{"GraphEmbedding", "[", RowBox[{InterpretationBox[StyleBox[RowBox[{"\[SkeletonIndicator]", "Graph:<", 51, ",", 51, ",", "Undirected", ">\[SkeletonIndicator]"}], ShowAutoStyles -> False, AutoSpacing -> False], Graph[{{{1, 2}}, {{2, 3}}, {{3, 4}}, {{4, 5}}, {{5, 6}}, {{6, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{8, 9}}, {{9, 10}}, {{11, 12}}, {{12, 13}}, {{13, 14}}, {{14, 15}}, {{15, 16}}, {{16, 17}}, {{17, 18}}, {{18, 19}}, {{19, 20}}, {{21, 22}}, {{22, 23}}, {{23, 24}}, {{24, 25}}, {{25, 26}}, {{26, 27}}, {{27, 28}}, {{28, 29}}, {{29, 30}}, {{31, 32}}, {{32, 33}}, {{33, 34}}, {{34, 35}}, {{35, 36}}, {{36, 37}}, {{37, 38}}, {{38, 39}}, {{39, 40}}, {{41, 42}}, {{42, 43}}, {{43, 44}}, {{44, 45}}, {{45, 46}}, {{46, 47}}, {{47, 48}}, {{48, 49}}, {{49, 50}}, {{51, 52}}, {{52, 53}}, {{53, 54}}, {{54, 55}}, {{55, 56}}, <<130>>}, {{{1., 1.}}, {{2., 1.}}, {{3., 1.}}, {{4., 1.}}, {{5., 1.}}, {{6., 1.}}, {{7., 1.}}, {{8., 1.}}, {{9., 1.}}, {{10., 1.}}, {{1., 2.}}, {{2., 2.}}, {{3., 2.}}, {{4., 2.}}, {{5., 2.}}, {{6., 2.}}, {{7., 2.}}, {{8., 2.}}, {{9., 2.}}, {{10., 2.}}, {{1., 3.}}, {{2., 3.}}, {{3., 3.}}, {{4., 3.}}, {{5., 3.}}, {{6., 3.}}, {{7., 3.}}, {{8., 3.}}, {{9., 3.}}, {{10., 3.}}, {{1., 4.}}, {{2., 4.}}, {{3., 4.}}, {{4., 4.}}, {{5., 4.}}, {{6., 4.}}, {{7., 4.}}, {{8., 4.}}, {{9., 4.}}, {{10., 4.}}, {{1., 5.}}, {{2., 5.}}, {{3., 5.}}, {{4., 5.}}, {{5., 5.}}, {{6., 5.}}, {{7., 5.}}, {{8., 5.}}, {{9., 5.}}, {{10., 5.}}, <<50>>}], Editable -> False], ",", "\"SpringEmbedding\""}], "]"}]. >>
```

I am new to Mathematica, so real sorry if this question is kind of stupid. Still learning how simbolic languages work.

Thank you in advance for the attention.

Comment: You need to use `GridGraph[{10, 10}]`.

Comment: Just tried and it didn't work. I have used `GridGraph[10,10]` in other applications, like `GraphPlot[GridGraph[10, 10], Method ->  "SpringEmbedding"]` and it worked fine. The problem is, I can plot the graph, but can't access the coordenates of each vertex. Any ideas?

Comment: Joao, `GridGraph[10,10]` throws the same error message in version 9.0.1.0 and version 10. Re "Just tried and it didn't work", i posted an answer showing that it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gg = GridGraph[{5, 5}];
from = GraphEmbedding[gg]
(* {{1., 1.}, {1., 2.}, {1., 3.}, {1., 4.}, {1., 5.}, {2., 1.},
    {2., 2.}, {2., 3.}, {2., 4.}, {2., 5.}, {3., 1.}, {3., 2.},
    {3., 3.}, {3., 4.}, {3., 5.}, {4., 1.}, {4., 2.}, {4., 3.}, 
    {4., 4.}, {4., 5.}, {5., 1.}, {5., 2.}, {5., 3.}, {5., 4.}, {5., 5.}} *)

to = GraphEmbedding[gg, "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
(* {{4.02435,0.101711}, {3.12171,0.0242386}, {2.05082,0.},
    {0.986007,0.0141666},{0.100658,0.0647508},{4.06179,0.979624},
    {3.13782,0.934741},{2.03782,0.921534},{0.94041,0.933663},
    {0.0249221,0.9603},{4.07303,2.03709},{3.14388,2.02199},
    {2.03717,2.02277},{0.930109,2.0302},{0.,2.03352},{4.04471,3.09303},
    {3.12995,3.11013},{2.04157,3.12253},{0.952442,3.12433},
    {0.033286,3.10491},{3.99021,3.97669},{3.10998,4.02691},{2.0532,4.05281},
    {0.990742,4.04081},{0.0962112,3.98637}} *)

{vl, el} = Through@{VertexList, EdgeList}@gg;

Animate[Graph[vl, el, 
    VertexCoordinates -> ( (1 - t) Rescale[from] + t Rescale[to])], 
 {t, 0, 1, .05}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but once again when I use `from = GraphEmbedding[gg]` it says: `"A graph object is expected at position 1 in \
GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{10,10}]]. "`

Do you believe maybe I have to import any other packages appart from Combinatorica`? Have any idea why this error is showing?

Comment: @JoãoRodarte, if you have `Combinatorica` loaded that might be the reason for the error messages. Start a new session and try the posted code  without loading `Combinatorica`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. Your exemple was enough for me to solve to problem.

Saved my life man. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Joao, my pleasure; glad it was useful for you. Welcome to mma.se.